# How do I avoid a "TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'" when computing list differences?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, set-operations

I'm using Python 3.8.  I have two lists, with each element being a dict ...

```
>>> existing_dicts = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
>>> cur_dicts = [{"id": 2}]
```

I wanted to find the dicts that were no longer in "cur_dicts" that were originally in "existing_dicts".  So in the above example,

```
{"id": 1}
```

is my desired result since it is in "existing_dicts" but not in "cur_dicts".  I tried the below to find the difference ...

```
>>> deleted_dicts = list(set(existing_dicts) - set(cur_dicts))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set approach is not working since your dictionaries elements of lists. It seems that turning lists of dictionaries into sets is not allowed.

Instead, you can use a list comprehension where you check if any element in the list `existing_dict` is in the `cur_dicts`,

```
 deleted_dicts = [x for x in existing_dicts if not (x in cur_dicts)]
```

If the dictionary is not in `cur_dicts`, it is added to `deleted_dicts`. This relies on the fact that dictionaries can be compared for equality with an `==` operator.

Full example, extended with duplicate entries and larger dictionaries:

```
existing_dicts = [{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 2, "id2" : 3}, {"id": 1, "id2": 2}]
cur_dicts = [{"id": 2}, {"id": 1, "id2": 2}]

deleted_dicts = [x for x in existing_dicts if not (x in cur_dicts)]
print(deleted_dicts)
```